# Rewrite this dictionary as literal

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently trying to create a dictionary from a tuple, but PyCharm tells me that my dictionary could be rewritten to dictionary literal.
I can't figure out how.

This is Python 2.7:

```
tb = traceback.extract_tb(ex_traceback)
my_stack = {'file': '', 'line': '', 'where': '', 'code': ''}
my_stack['file'], my_stack['line'], my_stack['where'], my_stack['code'] = tb[0]
print my_stack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(assuming `tb[0]` is a 4-tuple or similar)

The following would work, although it's not exactly a dict literal:

```
my_stack = dict(zip(("file", "line", "where", "code"), tb[0]))
```

I think what PyCharm means, though, is for you to do something like this:

```
my_stack = {
    'file': tb[0][0],
    'line': tb[0][1],
    'where': tb[0][2],
    'code': tb[0][3],
}
```

which is what that third line of your code is equivalent to, assumng `tb[0]` is a four-tuple.

If you want everything to be the *same* value, you can chain equals instead:

```
my_stack['file'] = my_stack['line'] = my_stack['where'] = my_stack['code'] = tb[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Put cursor to the given line and hit `Alt + Enter` and select `Replace dictionary creation` to see the result:

```
tb = traceback.extract_tb(ex_traceback)
my_stack = {'file': tb[0][0], 'line': tb[0][1], 'where': tb[0][2], 'code': tb[0][3]}
print my_stack
```